# How to use colored text in HTML or RGB notation without defining a color?

Tags: formatting, color, text

To write a colored text the syntax is

```
\textcolor{cornflowerblue}{my cornflowerblue text}
```

where `cornflowerblue` is previously defined in the preamble as

```
\definecolor{cornflowerblue}{rgb}{0.39, 0.58, 0.93}
```

Is it possibile color text like this?

```
\textcolor{#0033FF}{my colored text}
```

or

```
\textcolor{rgb(255, 0, 0)}{my colored text}
```

Comment: `\textcolor[rgb]{1,0,0}{my colored text}`

Comment: `\textcolor[HTML]{0033FF}{my colored text}`

Comment: Cornflowerblue is already defined by the `dvipsnames` and `svgnames` options of `xcolor`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `\textcolor` you can use an optional argument to specify a colour model.

For instance to use an `rgb` colour without defining a named colour you can use (of course this also works with other colour models such as `HTML`):

```
\documentclass[border=3.14]{standalone}

\usepackage{color}

\begin{document}
\textcolor[rgb]{1,0,0}{My colored text}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can do this quite easily by defining commands in the preamble.

[image]

Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newcommand{\textcolHTML}[2]{\definecolor{newcolorHTML}{HTML}{#1}\textcolor{newcolorHTML}{#2}}
\newcommand{\textcolRGB}[2]{\definecolor{newcolorRGB}{RGB}{#1}\textcolor{newcolorRGB}{#2}}

\begin{document}

Normal text. \textcolHTML{FF00B2}{First colored text}. \textcolHTML{195AFF}{Second colored text}.

\textcolRGB{5,220,30}{Some colored text defined by RGB values.}

\end{document}
```

You can also make a similar command for `rgb` by substituting `RGB` or `HTML` with `rgb` in the commands.